# Get ID from either Find or Insert, MongoDB

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor

I'm constantly using this pattern below. It seems a bit clunky to use two MongoDB calls for the job and I'm wondering if there's a better way to do it? I'm looking for the ID of the existing document, or.. I want to create a new one and use its ID. In Meteor, can I do this in one call?

```js
var thing_id;
var existing_doc = Things.findOne({name:'Thing One'});
if (existing_doc) thing_id = existing_doc._id;                              
else thing_id    = Things.insert({name:'Thing One'});
return thing_id;
```

Comment: Look at [upsert](https://docs.meteor.com/api/collections.html#Mongo-Collection-upsert)

Comment: This won't give the _id of the pre-existing doc as far I can work out.

Comment: I know that findAndModify() will do it natively but I'd need to reach down into the engine room. Possibly the way to go though...

Answer (score 1):

It is possible using `findAndModify`.

There is a package that adds this functionality (although I might do have done it a bit differently if I were to implement it myself).

```
$ meteor add fongandrew:find-and-modify
```

and its [repository on GitHub](https://github.com/fongandrew/meteor-find-and-modify).

It adds the raw method to the `Mongo.Collection`'s prototype and wraps async, such that it can be run using a fiber on the server.

You can get the raw output if you pass `true` as the second parameter.

Here's a short example with one insert and one update.

```js
> const Foo = new Mongo.Collection("foo");
> Foo.insert({foo: 1});
'6Mkpdjf3sXDZy6ioQ'
> Foo.findAndModify({query: {foo: 1}, update: {$set: {bar: 1}}, upsert: true}, true )
{ lastErrorObject: { updatedExisting: true, n: 1 },
  value: { _id: '6Mkpdjf3sXDZy6ioQ', foo: 1 },
  ok: 1 }
> Foo.findAndModify({query: {foo: 2}, update: {$set: {bar: 2}}, upsert: true}, true )
{ lastErrorObject: { updatedExisting: false, n: 1, upserted: 'y4eQzLWqCyBNr2WW9' },
  value: null,
  ok: 1 }
> Foo.findOne({foo: 2});
{ _id: 'y4eQzLWqCyBNr2WW9', foo: 2, bar: 2 }
>
```

You may need to do a bit of extra work to streamline it, in case you want to get the `_id` every time, but it is doable.

Comment: Thank you, @MasterAM, I'll give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

Even if an upsert doesn't give you the `_id` you can still use it to simplify your code down to:

```
 Things.upsert({name:'Thing One'});
 return Things.findOne({name:'Thing One')})._id;
```

Comment: Nice and neat. I'd be making exactly two calls every time though, as opposed to two only occasionally. I may be wrong?

Comment: You could always define your own function that wraps this whole thing to simplify upstream code. I don't think the extra db call is going to be very significant unless you're doing this 1000s times/second.